# How to print the value that must be formatted to width of binary value of n

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, format

```
def print_formatted(number):
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        a=oct(i)
        b=hex(i)
        c=bin(i)
        d=a.replace("0o","")
        e=b.replace("0x","")
        f=c.replace("0b","")
        print(i,end=" ")
        print(d,end=" ")
        print(e,end=" ")
        print(f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)
```

I have written this code but i dont have idea how to apply format function in this code to get the desired result

Comment: Can you also share the sample inputs and your desired output ? and what is it the outout you currently get from your code. It'll help us understand your problem better

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you wanted, but I think this might be it?

```py
def print_formatted(number):
    fstr = '{{:{}d}} {{:>{}}} {{:>{}}} {{:>{}}}'.format(len(str(number+1)),len(oct(number+1)),len(hex(number+1)),len(bin(number+1)))
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        a=oct(i)
        b=hex(i)
        c=bin(i)
        d=a.replace("0o","")
        e=b.replace("0x","")
        f=c.replace("0b","")
        print(fstr.format(i, d, e, f))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)
```